# SwiftUI: How to pass selected item back to parent using ViewModels

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, binding, combine

I'm trying to shape out the best way to pass the info back from child to parent when both use View Models and need the item to perform some work. There are a lot of similar topics on SO, but none seems to tackle the issue that I've got. I understand there might be multiple solutions to solve this project, but none of them convince me to be correct.

**Parent**

screen when you have a selected item and can save it later

```
struct ParentView: View {
    @StateObject viewModel = ParentViewModel()
}

class ParentViewModel: : ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedItem: Item?
    
    func saveSelectedItem() {
       // some logic to perform the request and save selectedItem, of course when it is not nil
    }
}
```

**ChildView**

Fetches all the possible items and allows selecting the item which should be later passed to parent.

```
struct ChildView: View {
    @StateObject viewModel = ChildViewModel()

    **(Problem)**
    
    // presents the list of all the items and highlights the current one (if not nil)
    // on click sends the info back to Parent
}

class ChildViewModel: : ObservableObject {
    @Published var items: [Item] = []
   
    **(Problem)**
    
    func loadItems() {
       // fetches the items and sorts them
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is to pass `selectedItem` to the `ChildView` and be notified when it is selected there on the list, but the child view model needs this to properly sort the items.

**PROBLEM**

1. What is the best approach to pass the `selectedItem` to the child and use it in `ViewModel`?

If I pass it as a `Binding` then the `ChildView` owns it, and I require this in my `ChildViewModel` to sort the items based on `selectedItem`.

If I perform an action to highlight the selected item based on state of the `ChildViewModel` (items) and `selectedItem` isn't a bit of a mess?

```
struct ChildView: View {
    @StateObject viewModel = ChildViewModel()
    @Binding var selectedItem: Item? // How can I use this in ChildViewModel, I need it to sort fetched items properly
}
```

2. I guess I should not pass binding to `ViewModel` as it is part of the SwiftUI framework?

```
class ChildViewModel: : ObservableObject {
    @Published var items: [Item] = []
    @Binding var selectedItem: Item? // I guess this is not correct, I don't even know how to pass it here
}
```

3. I know I can use completion block and initialize `ChildViewModel` with `wrappedValue` of the `selectedItem` but I would love to use SwiftUI/Combine approach.

Comment: Unless there's an extremely compelling reason, it's probably best to avoid multiple view models. You can use *one* `ObservableObject` and then use local `@State` if you need to in the child view(s).

Comment: @jnpdx do you mean that child should have the ParentViewModel as `ObservableObject`? I've got a feeling that it exposes too much

Answer (score 3):

In SwiftUI, you can use a combination of @Binding and @State to pass data back to a parent view.

Here's an example:

```
 struct ParentView: View {
  @State private var selectedItem: Item?

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      // Other views...

      ChildView(selectedItem: $selectedItem)
    }
  }
}

struct ChildView: View {
  @Binding var selectedItem: Item?

  var body: some View {
    List {
      // List of items...

      Button(action: {
        self.selectedItem = item
      }) {
        Text(item.name)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In this example, the ChildView has a selectedItem binding that is passed in from the parent view. When a user taps on one of the items in the list, the selectedItem is updated with the selected item. This change is automatically propagated back to the parent view because of the @Binding property wrapper.

Comment: in your example you completely removed the use of the view models that I need (to fetch the items and to sort them). I'm aware of `@State` and `@Binding` but it doesn't solve my problem to use `selectedItem` in child's ViewModel